# Liquid overwrite passed variable

Tags: shopify, liquid

Is there any way nowadays i can overwrite the value of page.title in liquid and reuse it afterwards?

```
Original title: {{ page.title }}
{% assign page.title = 'Goodbye World' %}
New title: {{ page.title }}
```

**Output:**

```
Original title: Hello World

New title: Hello World
```

It is an old issue but maybe there was an update in liquid?

*Source:* [Shopify/liquid/issues/302](https://github.com/Shopify/liquid/issues/302)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot change a read only value but you can capture the old value and use the captured one as you wish to same effect. Note the bonus of having two ways to do this!!

1. `{% capture old_title %}{{ page.title }}{% endcapture %}`
2. `{% assign old_title = page.title %}`

There is no way to do your funky pattern of changing the title, instead you are provided the luxury and bliss of variables to use!